# Advocacy - simple Tcl/Tk examples with screenshots?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Anyone know a web page with good, small examples of easy GUI creation in Tk and easy programming in Tcl? http://wiki.tcl.tk/1291 has a lot of examples, but only the larger ones have screenshots.

Comment: The ActiveState package has a 'demowidget' having lots of examples (I count 55 and a single widget can have many smaller features some really basic, some more advanced). This is where I get most of my ideas when it comes to Tk GUI. Though, as it is, the question is probably off-topic for being an off-site recommendation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer something more live than a screenshot; those don't show the power of *any* GUI toolkit. (You can mock a screenshot in photoshop, but a live interactive demonstrator is *hard* to fake!)

What you want is the widget demo. This is an application that is supplied with Tk which shows many things you can do with Tk's widgets. It's inspired a number of things I've written in the past, and showcases many of the features and capabilities of Tk in digestible pieces. You can watch the code in action, read the code that did it, and even change the code and rerun the demo to see how it changes (including whether you broke it).

---

If you're using Tk on **OS X**, launch the widget demo by running wish without any arguments and choosing `Run Widget Demo` from the default `File` menu. (That menu gets removed once you start defining your own menus, of course.)

If you've installed ActiveTcl on **Windows** (the normal way to install on that platform), the widget demo should be one of the entries in the ActiveTcl submenu/folder on the Start menu/screen.

I don't know whether the widget demo is included with default packaging of Tk on various Linuxes and other **Unix**es. (I think it *should* be, but I've not got an easy way to check from here. I know we ship it in the source distribution, but stuff gets hacked around by distros.) If you need to download it, you can get it as a ZIP direct from our source repository:

- For Tk **8.4**: http://core.tcl.tk/tk/zip?name=library/demos&ci=core-8-4-20
- For Tk **8.5**: http://core.tcl.tk/tk/zip?name=library/demos&ci=core-8-5-15
- For Tk **8.6**: http://core.tcl.tk/tk/zip?name=library/demos&ci=core-8-6-1

<sup>If you look at those URLs, you might be able to guess a pattern…</sup>

Comment: We _try_ to give each major feature of Tk its own demo in the widget demo. (There are a few other demos in that directory, but the one you want is called “widget”. Unsurprisingly. It `source`s the *.tcl files in the same directory, and uses the images in the …/images dir. Also, “rmt” is a forebear for the — excellent — Tkcon app/library.)

Comment: Normally, I wouldn't do recommendations on Stack Overflow, but recommending a part of Tk itself is acceptable IMO.

Comment: Links are broken…does Fossil still provide a way to get a ZIP of a directory?

Answer (score 2):

I found [tkdocs](http://www.tkdocs.com/) very useful.

This site also contain examples in Perl, Python and Ruby